# How to set up Android emulator proxy settings

Tags: android, browser, proxy, android-emulator

I want to to use the browser inside the Android emulator, and I want to use the proxy settings on my machine. How can I set this up?

Reading the very good Android manuals, they tell me that I should start Android using the following command:

```
emulator -avd myavd -http-proxy http://168.192.1.2:3300
```

But I am still not able to use the emulator browser. Please note that I am using the IP address for my proxy server.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 153):

The simplest and the best way is to do the following:
This has been done for Android Emulator 2.2

1. Click on Menu
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Wireless & Networks
4. Go to Mobile Networks
5. Go to Access Point Names
6. Here you will Telkila Internet, click on it.
7. In the Edit access point section, input the "proxy" and "port"
8. Also provide the Username and Password, rest of the fields leave them blank.

Comment: Does not work with the most common use case of running Fiddler2 or other proxy on localhost.... probably adding port forwarding, but that is a pain too

Comment: It doesn't work on Android emulator 2.3.3, but works on emulator 4.1.2 for me.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore on android 5 images (api 21)

Comment: this answer should be the accepted one! Works with Burpsuite on mac!

Comment: this also worked with Volley! added just in case someone was grepping that.

Answer (score 57):

[image: -http-proxy on Android Emulator]

On Run Configuration> Android Application > App > Target > Additional Emulator Command Line Options:  -http-proxy http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080

Comment: what eclipse version is that? i don't see this interface :(

Comment: also configure your emulator

Comment: for proxy with username and password use this format: `-http-proxy  http://username:password@host:port`

Comment: error `emulator is not recognized as a command` in my case..do i need to add anything in PATH variable??. I am using Android Studio 1.0.1 and having proxy in my office system.

Answer (score 55):

There is a setting in Android emulator to set the proxy.
[image]

Comment: The reference is https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html#proxy

Comment: Worked for me. My ambient: MAC OS ambient + android emulator and parallels windows 7 with fiddler proxy

Comment: This setting never worked for me. I always have to start the emulator with the -http-proxy command to get it to work.

Comment: This menu has a reoccurring bug which is driving me nuts from mid 2017. Sometimes it works, sometimes not on the same AVD. Only re-creating the AVD could help reliably. At times the proxy falls off in the middle of a session! In the corporate environment that means I'm getting locked out from my account because of that shit.

Comment: Though, it looks like I have found the solution for now: configuring that fake wifi hotspot as above to use the proxy helps even though my proxy requires the authentication, which that hotspot configuration doesn't have at all. Just URL and port helped to restore the lost connectivity immediately.

Comment: This would always work for me with Charles. Now it suddenly stopped working, even if I write wrong proxy, emulator still has the internet

Comment: The Proxy tab is not available, if you launch the emulator in a tool window.
-> Got to Android Studio Settings - Tools - Emulator and uncheck "Launch in a tool window".

Answer (score 23):

On Android Studio:

Click on Edit Configuration under App Menu

[image]

1. Go to App or Android App (as default settings)
2. tap on Debugger
3. Tap on LLDB startup command
4. Tap +
5. Add you command `-http-proxy http://168.192.1.2:3300`

[image]

that`s it.

More cool stuff if you wanna use your PC IP, use this command:

- `-http-proxy "$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)":8888` on MacOS
- `-http-proxy "$(hostname -i)":8888` on Linux

====== UPDATE 23.2.2022 ======

Currently I'm using these commands for enable/disable proxy:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy 127.0.0.1:8889
```

or dynamically taking my pc as host

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy $(ipconfig getifaddr en0):8889
```

To disable that proxy use:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0
```

Comment: Did not work for me. I am able to access the link on Emulator browser but not through the app.

Comment: @RohitSingh you can try terminal : adb shell settings put global "http_proxy 192.168.0.111:8888" .  you can get IP from you current machine by $(ipconfig getifaddr en0)

Answer (score 22):

I tried after removing http in the server name and it worked for me.

`emulator -avd myavd -http-proxy 168.192.1.2:3300`

Comment: This works only for browser, but no app request is going through the proxy :(

Comment: @FelipeSabino were you able to figure out? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @RohitSingh I'm going through same issue,  were you able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Mab

Answer (score 14):

This will not help for the browser, but you can also define a proxy in your code to use with a HTTP client:

```
// proxy
private static final String PROXY = "123.123.123.123";
// proxy host
private static final HttpHost PROXY_HOST = new HttpHost(PROXY, 8080);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, PROXY_HOST);
```

Comment: You should not put "127.0.0.1" for String PROXY.

Comment: kuester2000 have a look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723494/access-internet-via-another-country-using-android

Answer (score 8):

For some `leanback` (TV) emulators you can use cmd:

`adb shell settings put global http_proxy 10.0.2.2:8888`

- `8888` - is a port of proxy on a local machine (host), so on a local machine the http proxy will be 127.0.0.1:8888

To remove proxy (run sequentially in cmd line):

`adb shell settings delete global http_proxy`

`adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_host ""`

`adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_port ""`

Comment: This is the best answer for me.

Answer (score 5):

For 2022 you can use adb command like below:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy "your_PC_IP:PORT_YOU_LISTEN"
```

and you can disable your proxy with command below:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0
```

Answer (score 4):

I had no luck until I tried setting the environment variable `http_proxy`

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

"If the -http-proxy  command is not supplied, the emulator looks up the http_proxy environment variable and automatically uses any value matching the  format described above."

Answer (score 3):

For setting proxy server we need to set `APNS` setting. To do this:

1. Go to Setting
2. Go to wireless and networks
3. Go to mobile networks
4. Go to access point names. Use menu to add new apns

   Set  Proxy = localhost

   Set Port = port that you are using to make proxy server, in my case it is 8989

   [For setting Name and apn  here is the link:](http://www.teletechnology.in/how-to-connect-usb-modem-to-android/)

   According to your `sim` card you can  see the table

Comment: "authentication via the proxy server was unsuccessful" proxy does not require auth and never saw any request according to tcp dump.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to delete default APN from emulator(in my case its T- mobile) and 
create new APN with your proxy settings.

Note: i have tried all command line options and also tried setting the proxy for
emulators default APN but nothing worked.

Comment: i was struggling for this more than a month but finally got it working... Thanks to @usergo his answer gave me this clue

Answer (score 2):

nothin of that worked
i am using eclipse on windows 64-bit:
do the folllowing steps... it worked for me:
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Launch -> Default Emulator Options
-http-proxy="http://10.1.8.30:8080"

in your eclipse window

Answer (score 2):

Sometime even after setting all it may not work. I have tried all the methods like

1. Setting the proxy in Emulator APN
2. Setting it thru eclipse preferences --> Android --> Launch

Nothing worked. Then I did the following which worked instantly.

Goto eclipse Run --> run configurations. Under Android Applications you can see you application. Now, on the right hand side click on the Target tab. Under the 'Additional Emulator Command line options' add the following.

**-dns-server <*DNS servers from your local machine upto three*> -http-proxy http://<*your proxy*>:<*your proxy port*>**

The catch here is that the DNS Server setting should be from your local system. Goto **cmd** prompt and run **ipconfig** to check your DNS servers. Same with the proxy server and port. Whatever works for your browser should be put in here.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your address is 168.192.1.2 and not 192.168.1.2?

Notice the swapped first two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which environment you are using to run the emulator, check the logs to see how the emulator is started. Mine is started as:

*C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23*

Then you add the -http-proxy option, in my case:

*C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23* ***-http-proxy 192.168.0.22:8888***

Answer (score 2):

Install [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/download.htm) in your host computer. [Setup proxifier to use your proxy](https://www.proxifier.com/documentation/v3/quick.htm). You don't need to do anything else. You will be fine. Proxifier traps the calls from the system (including the android emulator) and route it through the configured proxy.

Comment: Note that Proxifier is a commercial software that have to be bought.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you are under proxy environment and internet is not running in your emulator, then please don't change any setting in emulator. Go to your eclipse project, right click , click on "Run as" then click on "Run Configuration". 
In pop up window choose "Target" and scroll down a little,
you will find "Additional Emulator Command Line Options"
Enter your proxy setting here in "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" as i entered

-http-proxy http://ee11s040:Om1l2ng3d4n2!08@hproxy.iitm.ac.in:3128

[image]

Then start a new Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to set corporate proxy with ntlm authentication is to use cntlm:

http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

Install and configure in C:\Program Files\Cntlm\cntlm.ini 
By default cntlm, listens to 127.0.0.1:3128

In android device set a new APN with proxy host 10.0.2.2 and port 3128
10.0.2.2 is a special alias to your host loopback interface (127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

see also 
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In console start the next command:

```
emulator -avd emulator_name -http-proxy you_proxy_ip_address:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the proxy in your app. This can be done using Settings class.
For example you can add following line to your "onCreate" method.

```
 Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.HTTP_PROXY, "myproxy:8080");
```

To change the proxy settings you have to have the android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

For `mitmproxy`,  I needed to use `emulator -avd some_avd -http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080` instead of using `localhost`.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the easiest thing is to use an emulator with Google Play and download a VPN client on it (f.e. Cisco Anyconnect Client)

Then configure the VPN on the emulator and access will be resolved.