# Logging HTTP requests/responses with Fiddler on Android emulator

Tags: android, http, android-emulator, fiddler

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) manages to log all my PC HTTP traffic, but when I run Android emulator and start browsing web though emulator, nothing gets logged.

Why isn't Fiddler logging Android emulator browser HTTP traffic?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Emulator has to be aware of Fiddler, just like your normal PC browsers are. When you want Fiddler to log your IE activity, you have to set up Fiddler as a IE proxy (actually, it happens automatically, but still).

- Here's some info on how to manually link Fiddler with browser: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp
- Here's some info on how to set up proxy in Android Emulator: [How to setup Android emulator proxy settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-setup-android-emulator-proxy-settings)
- Here's all in one: http://aurir.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/tutorial-getting-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler-http-proxy-tool/

Comment: Now it logs my browser http traffic, thank you. But why isn't the HTTP traffic of my own app logged?

Comment: I haven't tried it personally, but in point 2 of my answer there's some sample code of how to set up proxy in your own application. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the detailed instructions in this video: [How To Configure Fiddler Proxy for Android Studio Emulator (HTTP/HTTPS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFJX8ETk2Mc)
I use Fiddler *v4.6.20171.9220* and it works for me.

**NOTE:** http_proxy env variable may be affecting other program's ability to connect to the internet, make sure remove the variable when not needed.