# Android ICS Emulator No Network Showing

Tags: android, android-internet

In My emulator network is not showing, so that i'm unable to access internet...

I enabled 2G Only in mobile networks no use, checked for Airplane mode

I tried start emulator using this also no use \tools\emulator -avd  -dns-server 8.8.8.8

and tried all the things given in this link [No internet on Android emulator - why and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix)

[image]

Please please suggest how do i get network or internet...

Thanks in advance

Comment: need more info. can you access internet normally (on browser)? Are you behind a proxy? Have you tried another connection (wifi), or wireless datacard

Comment: When i use mobile browser "Webpage not available" message will come. I dont have wifi with me so i didn't that alternative. While creating APN i given valid proxy, port of this Network.. Same proxy and port settings working for PC

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-setup-android-emulator-proxy-settings

Comment: No i'll try now thanks for suggestion..:)

Comment: let me know if it works. I'll post it as an answer for posterity to refer to.