# How to do proxy setting in Android Virtual machine

Tags: android, proxy, virtual-machine

I use proxy connection to connect to internet.

I installed Android in VMware Workstation using ISO found [here](http://www.android-x86.org/download).

Everything went smooth including DHCP ip allocation and settings. But i can't figure out any way to setup proxy setting in Android. I know DHCP settings are correct because i am able to surf LOCAL INTRANET sites.

Now, i tried setting environmental variables of proxy (http / / user:pass@server:port) as in Debian/FreeBSD/Redhat but no help. Finally i googled and found a way to use applications to configure proxy. But it needs my device to be rooted. And i can't figure out how to root my virtual machine as all tutorials are only for device and emulaters.

So, finally how can i setup proxy setting in my VIRTUAL MACHINE. or how do i root my virtual machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup Android emulator proxy settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-setup-android-emulator-proxy-settings)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android is not capable of picking a proxy up from DHCP - researched it myself. Using ISC DHCPd with the settings that are working fine with Windows guests an Android virtual machine was totally unable to pick up a proxy. It can be a security "bug/feature", but it's a bogus one, IMHO... Maybe DNS-based auto-discovery method will help you? But be aware of a fact, that DNS-based proxy discovery is not system-wide and depends on application doing it.

Comment: Just as i thought. But is there a way to root my Virtual Machine?