# Unable to access apps for proxy internet connections

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, selenium-webdriver, http-proxy

I am facing an issue on opening apps when working from office network using android emulator. I am using Android 4.4.2 with API 19. I know there is a proxy defined to access the network & I have set the same at the below path:

**Settings->Wireless&Networks->MobileNetworks->AccessPointNames->Edit-> Set the Proxy, Port, Username & Password**

On applying the above settings, I am able to access internet on the emulator browser however still facing issues the issue on accessing apps.

Request you all to please provide any suggestion/advice to overcome from this issue. I know there are many threads asking about the same however I did not find any in which the issue while opening the apps got resolved.

Regards,
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

There is a emulator-wide setting for using HTTP proxy:
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#proxy as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12940297/1356130

Comment: Hi Atok,
With the first link, I am able to set the proxy however it is good for the emulator browser only. The applications are still not working. 
With the second link, I have a Java project in which I am testing a mobile application on an android emulator using selendroid. So setting the Run Configuration would not help much.

Got stuck at the moment.

Regards,
Anuj