# Android emulator proxy setting

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator

I am trying to set up a network proxy to view emulator traffic.

Now if I make a change in network settings of emulator ( 10.0.2.2:< port >, things work fine.
But if I try to set the proxy through command line using **emulator -avd myAvd -http-proxy localhost:< port >** , SSL traffic does not go through and I get time out errors.

Anyone has been able to get this working ?

Thanks

Comment: A useful to flag to append to your `emulator -avd` command is `-debug-proxy`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Android emulator proxy settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-setup-android-emulator-proxy-settings)

Answer (score 78):

Not sure which emulator you are using, but there is an issue with `new` Android emulator announced with Android Studio 2 - [Bug Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=201402)

To get a workaround, I had to do the following using the `new` emulator set to API 23:

1. Pass `-http-proxy http://192.168.x.x:yyyy` as a flag when you are launching the emulator. [For details how to do this, see here.](https://subsymbolic.net/2016/02/21/setting-a-proxy-in-android/)
2. Configure the `Access Point` settings for the proxy within the emulator. To do this, you go to *settings*->*more*->*cellular network*->*access point names* and edit the existing Access Point.
3. Finally, there is a setting in `Developer Settings` for configuring the device to use the legacy DHCP client instead of the new one. This must be configured to use the legacy one.
4. Toggle `Airplane` mode on and off.

[image: Access point settings for proxy]
[image: Developer settings for DHCP client]

Comment: hi i tried as you described but still not working, the same value for chrome but in emulator no

Comment: Worked, if you have an user/password for your proxy, you need to launch chrome / webbrowser to set them there too.

Comment: I see no Legacy DHCP option now. How to make it work now?

Comment: For me step 4 helped. Without it it refused to work. Thanks man.

Comment: Or just use proxifier. Much easier for me to achieve the same. It also forces to use proxy for all android apps that usually ignore sys proxy because of security.

Comment: step 1 is necessary for me. strange

Comment: in fact, only step 2 is enough, the other is not necessary.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked for me - omitting step 1 and Legacy DHCP step, as I didn't have that option.

Answer (score 8):

Check out comment #6 on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201402#c6. If you use your computers LAN IP setting the proxy works using the -http-proxy command line switch and no other workarounds are necessary.

For example:

```
$ emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23 -http-proxy http://10.102.80.149:8888
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had to set up a sniffing environment to debug some Android SSL traffic.

It seems now that you no longer need to set the proxy on the emulator's access point (steps 2-4 on @craig-russell's answer). Adding the `-http-proxy` launch parameter is enough. Also tried on API levels < 23 and succeeded.

My specs:
Android Studio 2.3.1
Windows 10
Android emulator version 25.2.5.0

Full details: http://www.devsbedevin.net/debugging-android-ssl-traffic/

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that your proxy server returns some additional HTTP headers in its response to Android emulator's HTTP CONNECT request. If so, you may encountered [a known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37002564) which should've been fixed by now, but due to desync between development branches, the fix has never been released. Please see [my comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37002564#comment10) for the details.

To clarify, HTTP requests are unaffected by the issue because they don't rely on connection tunneling (i.e. HTTP CONNECT), being delivered via HTTP Message Forwarding defined in [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.7) instead.