# Set proxy host for Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to set the host for a Firebase Firestore instance and in `FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()` I have a method `setHost()` which works with grpc.

But grpc doesn't support java socks currently.
How can I set a Socks5h proxy for Firebase Firestore?

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    .setHost("socks:///12.3.456.789:1234") //i'ts my proxy
    .builder()
```

I tried this: `socks:///`, `socks5:///`, `socks5h:///`
It didn't work, throwing a `NameResolver` exception.

Answer (score 0):

That method in builder is not to set your proxy, but is so you can "Sets the host of the Firestore backend." https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder

I think you want to setup the proxy on your device or emulator so that the Firebase connections are proxied appropriately.  [Android emulator proxy setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502437/android-emulator-proxy-setting)

Comment: thx for answer, but what i ask - then i need. In my country firestore servers are partially blocked and i want for my client enable proxy, if this real. I set up proxy for OkHttpClient and connect to my api work, but several functional (chat) don't work and i search solution)

Comment: Seems like a Question here had some answers, but I don't think any were conclusive:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133703/firebase-notification-not-received-behind-proxy

Comment: how does a sample "host of the Firestore backend." look like?

Comment: how does a sample "host of the Firestore backend." look like?