# Android emulator https proxy

Tags: android, android-emulator, http-proxy

I'm building an app (android + iOS) that needs to be able to reach an API Endpoint through a https proxy.
The development environment is Android Studio + Xcode + macOS.

My development path is:

1. Reach the endponit using android emulator settings.
2. Reach the endpoint using real andorid device settings.
3. Reach the endpoint using inapp solution implenting the https proxy connection management inside the app.

Since I'm at the first point, my problem is that I'm not able to setup the Android emulator with the https proxy.
(For iOS app, just setting up the mac network preferences is enought)
In Android, I successly set up the http, but not the https.

I have tried setting up the apn at the vitrual device, and running the emulator with `-http-proxy`. 
According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html) it includes https proxy, but it still not working.
The debugger saids that the server response is null when calling https. Http redirects to https.

All of those solutions just works for the http, not for the https.
I have also tried whit genymotion with no success.

I have tested the API from my computer (via postman) and it is all ok.

Has anyone been able to successfully access an https proxy from the Android emulator? It's possible? What settings am I omitting?

Thank you so much in advance.

PS: My problem is related with HTTPS, I am able to use HTTP proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup Android emulator proxy settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-setup-android-emulator-proxy-settings)

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Unfortunately I could not find any solution. So i submitted an issue to google.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73864692

lets hope the best!