# Android Emulator Repeatedly Drops Charles Proxy

Tags: android-studio, charles-proxy

Wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior. My Android emulator does not like being proxied by Charles. It 'drops' the charles proxy multiple times per day.

This is not a Charles setup issue. I know how to set up Charles, how to proxy the emulator, how to set up a certificate, how to control the access settings, etc. The proxy works fine, when it is working.

The issue is that the proxy will go along working just as it should, and then it just stops. I stop seeing network traffic in Charles and when I check the AndroidWiFi network in the emulator, it says 'connected, no internet'. To fix it, I just forget the network, select the AndroidWiFi network again, and go through the proxy steps (Proxy: Manual, Proxy hostname: , Proxy port: 8888).

I've deleted and re-installed the emulator. I have a licensed version of Charles.

This is baffling. Has anyone seen this? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-set-up-android-emulator-proxy-settings did you try this solutions?